# Why is the word "problem" forbidden in titles?

Tags: discussion, title, quality-filter

I have a title for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613676/does-mysql-optimize-selected-aggregations-on-related-tables-to-avoid-n1):

```
Does MySQL optimize selected aggregations on related tables to avoid N+1?
```

I had to rename it. The original was:

```
Does MySQL optimize selected aggregations on related tables to avoid N+1 problem?
```

Which was not accepted for submission.

Many times I had to replace the word "problem" with the word "issue". It was accepted. Titles were descriptive like:

- [GEvent / GUnicorn and the C10k issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684781/gevent-gunicorn-and-the-c10k-issue) (this one is mine)
- [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)
- [Youtube iframe wmode issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050999/youtube-iframe-wmode-issue)

The first one is mine, and although I used "issue", I wanted to use the word "problem" but with the meaning of a theoretical (or well-known design/technical, like C10k or N+1 as I noted) problem like:

- Traveling Salesman problem.
- "P <> NP?" problem.
- Hamiltonian Path problem.
- Dijkstra's Critical Path problem.

So: Why is the word "problem" so taboo, while words like "issue" are accepted, have fewer meanings, and such meanings collide with the "tabooed" version of "problem"? Has the theoretical meaning of "problem" been considered when the word was banned?

Comment: It was a failed experiment in trying to encourage people to write better titles for their questions. You're not the first person, nor the last, to complain about it.

Comment: Start reading [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/why-cant-we-use-the-word-problem-in-titles), and follow through to the linked questions.

Comment: The four examples you cite are legitimate uses of the word 'problem'. However they are much rarer than poor-quality titles that feature the same word, such as 'Please help me with my problem', 'Problem with SQL' -- it is in most cases redundant, and in most cases the OP should reword. Maybe they should allow users of a certain rep to use it? Not sure, since there are plenty of mid-rep users who will cheerfully rip up every rule in the style guide!

Comment: The example question titles with "issue" are bad. "Issue" is nondescriptive, just like "problem" is - what's "iframe wmode issue" supposed to tell me? The actual problem there is the "wmode" parameter is missing, thus a good title would be something like "wmode missing when embedding youtube iframe". Similar for the C10k question: stop using buzzwords and focus on the _specific_ problem. All I know from reading the title is you have an issue with many connections, but that's extremely broad. For the OOM question, the word to use would be "error" instead of "issue". TL;DR write better titles...

Comment: TBH the question would have been better if you had omitted more than one word: "Does MySQL optimize selected aggregations on related tables?" Speculating about the reason isn't relevant.

Comment: @halfer How long does it take for an average poor-question-asker to find out that rewording the title to 'prolbem' solves the problem with 'problem'?

Comment: @l4mpi your suggestion about C10k is not taking into account the main subject of the question. C10k is not an error I got, but a theoretical problem/technical limitation of threaded design for web connections. It is widely referred as a "problem" since it's a well known, say, "challenge"

Comment: @LuisMasuelli but C10k is not a _specific problem_, it is more like a description of a limitation of specific architectures. Without specifying the architecture and a whole lot of other specific details, any discussion of it would simply be too broad, thus using it as a title does not narrow down the subject enough. Your post contains three specific questions (which arguably should be asked as separate questions, especially the django one as it only indirectly fits the other two) which don't contain any reference to C10k, so you _can_ ask about your specific problems without mentioning it.

Comment: @MSalters perhaps you're right, but since there's a goal to achieve/avoid with doing that -besides the goal of avoiding useless comments like "what's specificly your goal here?" or "why would you need that in such query?" by people who cannot at-first-glance measure the impact of a worngly-designed query which would kill your database performance-, I had to explain the reason. Also, to not fall in an *XY problem* (perhaps there was an alternative way).

Comment: @LuisMasuelli: True, but that's why there's a big textbox below the title question. A good title invites an answer that doesn't just address your particular case, but also allows for generalization.