# How should I ask about the "thundering herd problem"?

Tags: support, title

Stackoverflow won't let me post a question about the [thundering herd problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem) (also [here](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/T/thundering-herd-problem.html)) because the word *problem* is not allowed in post titles.

What's the recommended solution?

Comment: Pr0blem????????

Comment: Use leetspeak or make a typo on purpose.

Comment: That's horrible. :-(

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That looks like a duplicate but it has no answer, so it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: On the other hand, what is your question really about and what title did you have in mind?

Comment: suggestion withdrawn

Comment: @CodeCaster I was trying to fix the title on http://stackoverflow.com/q/24239170/1848654.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why is the word “problem” forbidden in titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270386/2564301); the comments in there redirect to Meta's [Why can't we use the word “problem” in titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/why-cant-we-use-the-word-problem-in-titles). Note that [workarounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39483244/can-the-halting-prοblem-be-sοlved-for-certain-finite-functions) are frowned upon because search engines have a pr0blem with that. (Which is a reasonable point of view.)

Comment: A simple solution to this particular case is to use the technical term that isn't a proper name -- "Lock Convoy".

Comment: That restriction is pretty crude but just using "Thundering Herd" shouldn't affect things too much, except for maybe a person or two searching about Marshall University's football team.